# Change Menu Structure For Joomla Site

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I found this tutorial of how to create a menu like I want in `CSS` and I can have it working in a stand-alone version.  My question is, which one of my Joomla files would I need to add this coding to in order for my Joomla site to have this same look?

[Menu Format I want](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)

Comment: Are you developing a custom template extension for this Joomla instance?

Comment: Just wanting to modify the look of the "default" joomla look.  The template that is installed when you 1st install joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know the best solution without know what your template is.  However, I would recommend creating a module override for the menu module, then editing the files.

The easiest way to create overides in Joomla is via the templates section of Joomla admin.  If your template is the standard Protostar one, then you'd take the following steps...

1. Login to your site's administrator area, ie mysite.com/administrator
2. Under the "Extentions" menu, click "Templates" then "Templates" again.
3. Click on your template in the list of templates
4. Click on the "Create Overides" tab.
5. Under the "Modules" header click on "mod_menu".

You've now created a template override for the menu module.  Now you can edit the code.  If you did the above with the Protostar template, you will find the files in "templates/protostar/html/mod_menu".  In the folder you'll see a "default.php" which is the main code for the menu, this loads child files for the various menu types, "default_component.php", "default_heading.php", "default_separator.php" and "default_url.php".

Further reading...

- https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Currently my template is the default template that comes with joomla.  I just did a fresh install (or maybe the term would be new install) and I am wanting to customize the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The front-end menus and page positions are generated from template. Look into Your_site/templates drive and locate your template there. Most templates directly use page layout in their index.php

Comment: Thank you for giving me the location to brose.  Looking there now.

Comment: mark this as accepted answer, if it solves your issue, so that it can help other community members